# How to enable mongo connection pool monitoring with spring-data-mongodb in XML?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongodb 1.10.12 with mongo 3.6.4. I recently upgraded from a lower version of mongo, and now my mongo connection pool monitoring is broken because there is no ConnectionPoolStatisticsMBean registered. According to the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/reference/monitoring/) for that version of mongo "JMX connection pool monitoring is disabled by default. To enable it add a com.mongodb.management.JMXConnectionPoolListener instance via MongoClientOptions"

However, in the xml schema for spring-data-mongo, the clientOptionsType does not allow setting that value, unless I am missing something. Is there any way, with spring-data-mongodb, to turn on the connection pool monitoring through xml?

Here is my xml for the mongo beans

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongo"
                    host="${mongo.hostname:#{null}}"
                    replica-set="${mongo.replica.set:#{null}}"
                    port="${mongo.port}"
                    credentials="'${mongo.username}:${mongo.password}@${mongo.auth.db.name}?uri.authMechanism=${mongo.auth.mechanism:SCRAM-SHA-1}'"
>
    <mongo:client-options connections-per-host="${mongo.connections-per-host:40}"
                          threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="${mongo.threads-blocked-per-connection:3}"
                          connect-timeout="${mongo.connection-timeout:10000}"
                          max-wait-time="${mongo.maxWaitTime:120000}"
                          socket-keep-alive="${mongo.socketKeepAlive:true}"
                          socket-timeout="${mongo.socketTimeout:0}"
                          read-preference="${mongo.read.preference:PRIMARY_PREFERRED}"
                          write-concern="${mongo.write.concern:ACKNOWLEDGED}"
    />
</mongo:mongo-client>
```

and my pom dependencies

```
<properties>
    <mongo-version>3.6.4</mongo-version>
    <spring-data-version>1.10.12.RELEASE</spring-data-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${mongo-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that there is no way, through the spring-data-mongodb schema, to add a connection pool listener, but the folks that maintain the repo suggested a solution which is to use a BeanPostProcessor to alter the MongoClientOptions before they are passed to the mongo client like so

```
@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

    if (bean instanceof MongoClientOptions) {
        return MongoClientOptions.builder((MongoClientOptions) bean)
            .addConnectionPoolListener(new JMXConnectionPoolListener()).build();
    }
    return bean;
}
```

Doing so successfully registered ConnectionPoolStatisticsMBeans for me

Answer (score 1):

I tackled the very same challenge. In my case, originally the Spring configuration was done using XML. I have managed to combine the XML configuration with Java configuration, because the *Java configuration* gives you more flexibility to configure the `MongoClientOptions`:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoClientWrapper {

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() 
    {
        //credentials:
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "auth-db", "password".toCharArray());

        MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .addConnectionPoolListener(new MyConnectionPoolListener())
                .build();
        return new MongoClient(
                new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),      //replica-set
                Arrays.asList(credential)
                ,options
                );
    }


    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate()
    {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), database);
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

In my project, adding the BeanPostProcessor was useless, because the MongoClientOptions Bean was not automatically instantiate.
I had to create Bean manually to add a connection pool listener in my environment:

```
@Bean public MongoClientOptions myMongoClientOptions() {
      return MongoClientOptions.builder().addConnectionPoolListener(new JMXConnectionPoolListener()).build();
}
```